How do I fix mapping when exporting from Blender to Unity?
When I export from Blender to Unity via FBX, my tiled texture mapping is lost. Not only it is lost, but also mapping is planar from the top of the model in Unity and I cannot figure out how to fix it.
Please see the video to see the issue.
https://youtu.be/jXyig6i6snQ
I tried all different FBX export settings.
I tried rotating and saving the object to retain planar projection from the top which Unity applied.
I've recalculated the normals of the object but also no results.

Is the wrap mode for your texture inside Unity set to "Clamp" instead of "Repeat"? If so, change it to "Repeat".

There's nothing wrong with the model / the FBX exported from Blender, rather the problem lies in the texture's wrap mode in Unity. Make sure that inside your texture's import settings, the "Wrap Mode" is set to "Repeat" instead of "Clamp":

(Image edited from https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/texture-type-default.html)
